# Disable dragging of selected object in Piccolo2d?

Tags: java

I know Piccolo2d is an old project, but I have a couple of questions.

1) Is it possible to disable dragging a selected object? For this particular use case, I only want to select an object, not move or delete it. I know I can disable deletion using:

```
    this.selector.setDeleteKeyActive(false);
```

But I don't see an option to disable dragging. Is the only option to override the drag functionality in the event handler?

2) Is there no way to have the selection handler active at the same time as the pan/zoom handlers? It seems a bit archaic to disable pan/zoom when you want to support object picking. Or do I have to create my own handlers?

My current code is:

```
...
this.pluginContext.getCanvas().setPanEventHandler(null);
this.selector = new PSelectionEventHandler(this.mapLayer.getNode(), this.mapLayer.getNode()) {
};
this.selector.setDeleteKeyActive(false);
this.pluginContext.getCanvas().addInputEventListener(this.selector);

PNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addListener(this, "nodeSelected",
        PSelectionEventHandler.SELECTION_CHANGED_NOTIFICATION, this.selector);
...


public void nodeSelected(final PNotification notification) {
    logger.debug("Selection - " + this.selector.getSelection().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In true developer tradition, I found an answer.

My pickable nodes are all grouped under individual grouping nodes. This lets me add an event listener on the grouping node, like this:

```
    groupNode.addInputEventListener(new PBasicInputEventHandler() {

        public void mouseReleased(final PInputEvent event) {

            PNode node = event.getPickedNode();
            if (node != null) {
                onNodeSelected(node); // your logic here
            }
        }
    });
```

The beauty of this is that the event contains the picked node that is grouped under that group node. Perfect! Also, you don't have to disable the pan/zoom handlers.

The only downside is that this doesn't give you the selection decorator around the node. Can't win 'em all!